# C Multidimensional Array: Am I missing something?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm currently learning C, and I have just written a draft of a program that allows a user to move a player around a character-based maze/path. I have built the maze/path as multidimensional character array, with a while loop controlling the player's position by replacing certain characters in the array. Here is the multidimensional array I have initialised:

```
char maze[5][7] = {
    {"_", "_", "_", "_", "_"},
    {"|", " ", " ", " ", "|"},
    {"|", " ", "|", " ", "|"},
    {"|", " ", "|", "_", "|"},
    {"|", "_", " ", " ", "|"},
    {"|", " ", "|", " ", "|"},
    {"|", "_", "_", "_", "|"}
};
```

However, when I try to compile, I get this error:

```
error: '}' expected
```

The first row in the array is apparently missing some sort of closing bracket, although I have checked proper array syntax multiple times and this appears to be correct. What am I missing? Are there any other issues with this?

Comment: "|" is a string literal that has type of character array. '|'  is a character literal that has type char. You need to use character literals to initialize your array instead of string literals. And the array should be declared like char maze[7][5] that is it has 7 "rows" with 5 "columns"

Comment: First of all you got the dimensions wrong. Then you have an arrays of arrays of *characters* not strings. Finally, C doesn't have "multi-dimensional arrays", it only have arrays of arrays (of arrays...).

Comment: C arrays are **row major**. So your initializer is of the wrong size, as well as type.

Comment: Is your problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Your array is of type `char`, but your entries are of type `char *`. Replace double quotes `"` with single quotes `'`.

Single quotes represent `char` itself where double quotes represent char sequence (string) therefore compiler will try to add `\0` character to the end.

On the other hand, you have to swap values 5 and 7 for initialization.

End result is similar to this:

```
//7 big entries with 5 values
char maze[7][5] = {
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving wrong dimensions to the array `maze[5][7]` it is row and column and you definition says 7rows and 5 columns. And you are entering every element as an string. It should be a character which is given inside single quote  like this `'a'`. If you will define in double quote it will become string. This will solve your problem

```
char maze[7][5] = {
{'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
{'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
{'|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|'},
{'|', ' ', '|', '_', '|'},
{'|', '_', ' ', ' ', '|'},
{'|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|'},
{'|', '_', '_', '_', '|'}
};
```

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: Better answer would be to explain him why you did that and why his code is wrong.

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu a good answer is self-contained, but you can of course reference existing comments.

Comment: @FelixPalmen now it should be a complete answer i guess 

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace " with ' because a char is a single sign.
The second problem is, that you assign the length wrong.

Replace the first with the second length.

```
char maze[7][5] = {
    {'_', '_', '_', '_', '_'},
    {'|', ' ', ' ', ' ', '|'},
    {'|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|'},
    {'|', ' ', '|', '_', '|'},
    {'|', '_', ' ', ' ', '|'},
    {'|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|'},
    {'|', '_', '_', '_', '|'}
};
```